# How can I make widgets move from right to left on scroll using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, widget

I would like to know if there is a way to do something like this with Flutter. I need to get the widgets move from right to left on scroll. Please see the following GIF

https://ibb.co/9s3SgkW

Comment: image not working.
try to upload gif in stackoverflow directly
stack takes gif

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be an exact behavior match, but you could try my package [Entry](https://pub.dev/packages/entry), and more precisely `Entry.offset(xOffset)`